# How to "textjoin" with arrayformula (including ignoring empty cells)?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I love textjoin because of the "ignore empty cells" capability, it's really clean. However, it won't work with ArrayFormula to auto-populate a column for me. So it seems a messier workaround is needed. This is what I have come up with. Does anyone know of a simpler solution?

Formula in cell A2 should combine values in cells B, C, & D with a delimiter, and not have any extra delimiters like leading or trailing _s, or _ _ in the middle.

```
+----------------------+------------+------+-----------+
|       NiceName       | first_name | year |  country  |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----------+
| Kaylee_1999          | Kaylee     | 1999 |           |
| Selma_2003_Indonesia | Selma      | 2003 | Indonesia |
| Babbette_Morocco     | Babbette   |      | Morocco   |
| Erhart_1985_Japan    | Erhart     | 1985 | Japan     |
| 1997_France          |            | 1997 | France    |
| Derward_1985_China   | Derward    | 1985 | China     |
+----------------------+------------+------+-----------+


=arrayformula(substitute(if(isblank(B2:B),,B2:B&"_")&if(isblank(C2:C),,C2:C)&if(isblank(D2:D),,"_"&D2:D),"__","_"))
```

[screenshot of data & formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNk2A.png)

Comment: Just copy and paste the formula to other row will save your day lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your current set of data try

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(trim(transpose(query(transpose(B2:D),,rows(B2:B)))), " ", "_"))
```

and see if that works?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution to deal with double first names if they crop up (or Country names with a space). Cell `A2`:

`=arrayformula(regexreplace({B2:B&if(C2:C<>"","_"&C2:C&"_","_")&D2:D},"^\_|\_$",))`

[image]

I would also recommend adding an `array_constrain` to prevent the formula working all the way down the sheet.

`=arrayformula(array_constrain(regexreplace({B2:B&if(C2:C<>"","_"&C2:C&"_","_")&D2:D},"^\_|\_$",),MAX(IF(B:D<>"",ROW(B:B))),1))`

Also, to locate the formula in cell `A1`, with a heading, you can use:

`=arrayformula(array_constrain({"NiceName";regexreplace({B2:B&if(C2:C<>"","_"&C2:C&"_","_")&D2:D},"^\_|\_$",)},MAX(IF(B:D<>"",ROW(B:B))),1))`

[image]