Evaluate if a cell is empty in an array
data
I have this current formula in google Sheets
={"ID Vélo"; arrayformula(B2:B&"-"&C2:C&"-"&D2:D)}
If cells in B, C or D are empty, it retruns only --
I'd like to return nothing if there is nothing in the cells. How can I achieve this?
Thanks
When I try isblank function it returns an error

What error does it return?  What expression did you use to "try isblank function"?

You could try this formula:
={"ID Vélo"; ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:D),,ROWS(B2:B)))), " ", "-"))}

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67775457/20635660
Different question, but similar solution.  I just added the header row to provide the desired results.
